# Does there exist a smooth function with following properties?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

Let $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d; \mathbb{C})$.
Does there exist $g \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d; \mathbb{C})$ such that $g(x)f(x) = 0$ and $|g(x)|=1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant $|g(x)|=1$, but I wrote $|f(x)|=1$. I edited.

Comment: By standard inner product you mean $z\cdot w = z\overline{w}$ or the standard inner product of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: something like
$$
g(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
if(x)/|f(x)|&f(x)\neq0\\
0&f(x)=0\\
\end{array}
\right.?
$$

Comment: @heppoko_taroh - Is there any reason you refer to $\mathbb C$ rather than $\mathbb R^2$? It's caused confusion about the product.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I have corrected the description of inner product.

Comment: @heppoko_taroh - Now the answer is trivial, as shown by Jason's comment below.

Answer (score 2):

It may not exist. Consider a smooth function $\phi\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, $\phi(x) = \exp (-\frac{1}{x})$ for $x > 0$ and $\phi(x) = 0$ for $x\le 0$. Now take $f(x) = (\phi(x), \phi(-x))$.

$\bf{Added:}$

In the case where the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ we need the zero of $f$ to be of infinite order.

However, if the domain is $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{C}$, we have the example of $f(z) = z$.

Comment: Even easier:  if $f$ is non-zero at some point, then $fg = 0$ implies $g= 0$ at that point.  Then $|g| = 0$ at that point, not $1$.